# Using S3 as default file system

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, filesystems

Hi I am trying to use S3 as a default file system when working with Hive.
I have set up:

- fs.defaultFS=s3://mybucket
- fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId=myid
- fs.awsSecretAccessKey=mysecretkey

I can create databases and tables and they show up in my s3 bucket.
Problem occurs when I try to use those tables - selecting from them, inserting. I get an error:

```
Incomplete HDFS URI, no host: hdfs:/tmp/hive/hadoop/dir/filename
```

Problem is that it still uses hdfs instead of s3, what else should I set up to make Hive and MapReduce use S3 as FS?

Comment: Are you just trying to read/write tables? If so, `CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE` is the best way to use S3. Or are you needing to refer to actual files via a path?

Comment: Hi I would like to use s3 bucket instead of HDFS, I would create external table from source bucket that has unpartitioned data an would like to insert insert that data into new s3 bucket that would have partitioned parquet files. So for the  process of inserting I want MapReduce to use S3 as a memory and not HDFS because I would have unlimited memory with that approach.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to use hive and Amazon S3 is to launch and Amazon EMR cluster and use **External Tables** stored on S3.

For example, this statement creates a table that will be stored in S3:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE  parquet_hive (
    requestBeginTime string,
    adId string,
    impressionId string,
    referrer string,
    userAgent string,
    userCookie string,
    ip string
)
STORED AS PARQUET
LOCATION 's3://myBucket/myParquet/';
```

You could then insert data into it:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE parquet_hive
SELECT
  requestbegintime,
  adid,
  impressionid,
  referrer,
  useragent,
  usercookie,
  ip
FROM impressions;
```

See: [Converting to Columnar Formats](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/convert-to-columnar.html)

If you are using your own Hadoop cluster instead of Amazon S3, you *might* need some additional configuration to work with S3 (eg using `s3n:` or `s3a:`).

Comment: Yes I have that I just want one additional setup, i.e force MapReduce to use s3 as default file system when running insert operation. I don't have enough space on HDFS to handle the amount of data I want to process. I followed steps defined [here](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/87256/using-s3-as-defaultfs.html). When I create external table and new database all temp files are saved in bucket that I specify as a default FS but when it gets to the point of using MapReduce on insert it tries to get temp files from hdfs and not from s3.